# Disable autosave with `function.php` for custom post wordpress?

Tags: functions, revisions, autosave

I need disable auto save with function.php in wordpress. What should I do? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are a few methods to disable autosave/revisions.

#### Disabling autosave:

1. Using action and dequeuing the .js that is responsible for autosave, this goes into `functions.php`, located in the current theme directory.

```php
function bt_disable_autosave () {
    wp_deregister_script('autosave');
}
add_action('admin_init', 'bt_disable_autosave');
```

2. Using a constant to set the interval so high (one day) it will never happen unless you leave the browser open for that long, this goes into the `wp-config.php`, located in the root of the wordpress install.

```php
define('AUTOSAVE_INTERVAL', 86400);
```

---

#### Disabling/limiting revisions:

1. Limiting revisions using a constant, this goes into the `wp-config.php`, located in the root of your wordpress install.

```php
define('WP_POST_REVISIONS', 3);
```

2. Disabling revisions, this is the same as the above, you just set it to 0 instead.

```php
define('WP_POST_REVISIONS', 0);
// or
define('WP_POST_REVISIONS', false);
```

Comment: hey Buttered_Toast Thank you :) I used the first option and that does not work I would like to add the code to functions.php any idea why it is still autosaving?

Comment: Did you add it to the active theme functions.php? it's a better idea to create a child theme if you plan on adding custom code, that way next time the theme is updated you wont lose your custom code.

Comment: hey Buttered_Toast yes I added to child theme functions.php but still autosave is happening! can you help?

Comment: How do you know it's not working. I just pasted this code into my fresh wp install and the autosave is dequeued, how are you checking that your code works?